# Running Aggregates on Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, oop, sequelize.js

Hope y'all are doing well, coding along.

I'm a Junior Developer learning Sequelize, unfortunately after a few days of brute forcing I am unable to derive a solution for my problem.

Maybe one of you's can help me out?

I've have managed to Sum Data from my test DB into a given field called Total, which is a good halfway into what i need.

Now, the big challenge is, i got two little objects with the Total, but am unable to figure how to create a new object with the sum of sums!

Current Function:

```
const findTransactionNumberStuff = (Tsx: Array<string>) => {
  const Op = Sequelize.Op;
  return db.FinanceStuffs.findAll({
    where: { Tsx: { [Op.in]: Tsx } },
    group: ['Tsx'],
    attributes: ['Tsx', [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('Tsx')), 'total']],
  });
};
```

Work in Progress:

```
const findSummedTransactionNumberStuff = (Tsx: Array<string>) => {
  const Op = Sequelize.Op;
  return db.FinanceStuffs.findAll({
    where: { Tsx: { [Op.in]: Tsx } },
    group: ['Tsx'],
    attributes: ['Tsx', [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('Tsx')), 'total']],
    ['total', [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('total')), 'Summed']],
  });
};
```

Current Output:

```
Receives: Tsx: [01,02]
Outputs:

[
    {
        "Tsx": "01",
        "total": "200"
    },
    {
        "Tsx": "02",
        "total": "100"
    }
]
```

Wanted Output: (I don't even need the TSX Numbers if it's too difficult, Simply the Sum of all the totals)

```
{

     "Summed": "300"

}
```

My linter is not having a good time with this one.. Does anyone have any ideas?

Much appreciated!